# How to keep track of bug progress and feature request in web development projects?

Tags: debugging, workflow, bug-tracking, trac

I am trying to find the best way to maintain a bug tracker and feature/upgrade requests for clients on web development projects.  Ideally it would be an open source system we can have installed on a sub domain of our site.

This will then allow each client to login and add bugs/features/upgrade which we can hopefully keep track of.

I have been trying to use and implement [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) but it just feels too "techy" and a little too complex for setup.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Shadi

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify, we do want a system to install on our servers, the trouble with trac is the install process in relation to what you get and how clients feel about it is a little poor.  But if something is awesome but has a complex setup, that isn't a problem...

Answer (score 1):

Mantis is another. Simple UI.

http://www.mantisbt.org/

If you have Linux boxes, trac is much easier to install. Config takes a bit, but wasn't a problem in my experience.

Comment: Functional i guess, but scary to look at.  Unless nothing amazing pops up trac will remain in place i guess :)

Answer (score 0):

I've heard good things about [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/). :)
If you don't want to install it yourself they have a hosted solution also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look a [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/)? Not sure if it meets all your needs but it is free but you can get paid support. It's an open source project AFAIK.